# Origin of the title of "La Dragontea" by Lope de Vega?

Tags: poetry, spanish-language, title, lope-de-vega

Why Lope de Vega titled his poem [La Dragontea](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lope_de_Vega#La_dragontea), what were the prerequisites? I tried to search the etymology of this word but was not successful.

Yes, I know that Chinese [Dragon Tea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longjing_tea) exists, but I suppose it has nothing to do with Vega's poem, because Longjing tea was named Dragon Tea by English speakers, and Vega was a Spanish-speaking author, so this is irrelevant.

I also know an old music-hit [Dragostea Din Tei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragostea_Din_Tei) but this is ridiculous as this name has Romanian language origin :)

I've found couple of [researches](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/270122409_Lope_de_Vega_y_Ercilla_el_caso_de_La_Dragontea) about this book but they are all paid, so I cannot inspect them up.

Anybody knows the etymology or story of invention of this word? Some credible historical evidences?

Comment: Dragon is etymologically related to Drake, the protagonist. I'm not a Spanish speaker but could the -tea suffix be something like "the story of", like "The Odyssee" is to Odysseus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subject of Vega’s poem is the disastrous expedition of [Francis Drake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francis_Drake) against the Spanish colony of [Panamá](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panam%C3%A1_Viejo) in Central America, where he met his death of dysentery in 1596. ‘Drake’ of course means ‘dragon’, and Vega combined this with ‘tea’, meaning ‘fire-torch’ in Spanish, to produce an image of the English sailor as a fire-breathing dragon:

> Como el Alva sus parpados abria
>   estornudando resplandor intenso,
>   lamparas de su boca despedia,
>   de sus narices humo negro y denso
>
> His eyelids, raised, released the light of dawn;
>   His snorting breath lit up the heavens with fire;
>   His mouth sent tongues of flame into the sky;
>   His nostrils poured out black and smoking clouds.
>
> <sub>Lope Félix de Vega Carpio. ‘La Dragontea’, Canto X. In [*Coleccion de las Obras Sueltas* (1776), volume 3, p. 371](https://archive.org/details/colecciondelaso16vegagoog/page/n390/mode/2up). Madrid: Antonio de Sancha. The (somewhat fanciful) English translation is from Simon Schama (2015), *The Face of Britain*, Viking.</sub>

Comment: `Drake’ of course means ‘dragon’` in what language it means dragon? in English *drake* is a male duck, in Spanish there is no such word as well. I'm non-English and neither Spanish-native (though know it a litlle) so word *Drake* is pretty unlike to any other word I know in Eng/Esp

Comment: You might need a bigger dictionary! The *Oxford English Dictionary* says "drake, *n.* 1.a. = dragon" and the word goes back to the Old English poem *Beowulf*, in which the hero fights a "fyrdraca" (a fire-drake). The English word comes from Latin *draco*.

Comment: `You might need a bigger dictionary` indeed :) thanks for your guidance